# Как при загрузке файла выводить его название в отдельном input

Tags: html, css

Как при загрузке файла выводить его название в отдельном input? Есть input в типом File. Как мне сделать так, чтобы после загрузки файла его название отображалось в отдельном inpute ниже

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки реализовать это

Answer (score 0):

Оно?

```js
function showFile(input) {
  const file = input.files[0].name
  document.querySelector('#test').value = file
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="showFile(this)" />
<input id='test' />
```

Comment: Я сам дошёл до написания следующей функции:

    function showName(){
        var name = document.getElementById('upload-file');
        alert('Selected file: ' + name.files.item(0).name);
    }

Сейчас знаю как это вывести в инпут, спасибо